# samba isn't accessible from other computers in the network?

Tags: networking, server, samba

I'm having a server running Ubuntu 14.04. Recently I've set up a Samba-Server to share some files with the Windows computers in the network. It's working but only accessible from the machine where it's running.
It has a static IP: **`192.168.2.10`**

If I connect with: `smbclient //192.168.2.10/NAS -U NAS`, it works. But only one the server.
All the ports needed are opened with `GUFW`, using the Samba preset.

On other computers the server is visible, but if I connect to it I get a `NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error.

Here's my `smb.conf`, extracted with `testparm`:

```
[global]
        server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
        interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8, p5p1
        server role = standalone server
        map to guest = Bad User
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
        syslog = 0
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 1000
        load printers = No
        printcap name = /dev/null
        disable spoolss = Yes
        dns proxy = No
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        idmap config * : backend = tdb
        printing = bsd
        print command = lpr -r -P'%p' %s
        lpq command = lpq -P'%p'
        lprm command = lprm -P'%p' %j

[NAS]
        path = /home/NAS/NAS
        valid users = NAS
        read only = No
        guest ok = Yes
```

#### Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what p5p1 is on your server, but
please edit your interfaces-setting according to your subnet:

```
[global]
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8, 192.168.2.0/24, p5p1
    server role = standalone server
    ....
```

furthermore, also check your iptables if you have them enabled.

Comment: Got it! I configured the firewall through GUFW, but it wasn't activated.